# how to create smaller image

Tags: javascript, canvas

```
<img id='imgt' src='../img/crop.png' alt='img'>
```

Original size of `imgt` is larger than 960 x 540.
I need the same image in width 960px and height - auto.
Here is my try using canvas:

```
var c1 = document.createElement("canvas");
c1.width = 960;
var ctx = c1.getContext("2d");
var img=document.getElementById("imgt");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 960, auto);
```

Console says - `auto` is not defined` but I have no idea what to put as height param.

I tired without `height` param:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 960);
```

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': Valid arities are: [3, 5, 9], but 4 arguments provided.`

Any help?

Is there maybe another way to produce smaller image, without canvas?

Comment: the "height" parameter to the drawImage method is optional. Have you tried simply not passing it at all, or passing null?

Comment: do you actually need it on a canvas? Can you just create another `<img>` tag with different height/width properties specified? Are you trying to edit the image, or just display it differently?

Comment: @ADyson, yes I tried, please see my update. I need to download the new image (960 x auto), so I need a new image created, not just display it.

Comment: what about passing null for the height? does that work?

Comment: @ADyson, `ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 960, null);` creates image (960 x 150) and with some failure, it cannot be seen in any img preview application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try following code.

```
var c1 = document.createElement("canvas");
c1.width = 960;
var ctx = c1.getContext("2d");
var img=document.getElementById("imgt");

var _curWidth = c1.width;
var _autoHeight = (_curWidth / img.naturalWidth) * img.naturalHeight

ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, _curWidth, _autoHeight);
```

Comment: This gives me allways an image 150px height, regardless of various `naturalHeight`.

Comment: are you giving height to image using css ??

Comment: No, the new image is not displayed at all, I have a code to download it. If displayed it is also allways 150px height. Maybe `c1.height` should be defined?

Comment: can you create jsfeddle snippet for this for better understanding

Comment: what is the issue ?? i am not getting can you please elaborate

Comment: Solved. I just added `c1.height = _autoHeight;` to your code. Thanks a lot for your time an patience.